# Efficient 1000Hz clock with Web Workers

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, frequency, web-worker

Creating a max-speed clock using setInterval only yields a maximum frequency of about 250Hz. For the project I'm working on I need a way faster clock. However, I do not want to run a 1000Hz clock in the main thread because of obvious reasons.

For now, the only plausible way I managed to reach a frequency of 1000Hz is by creating a second worker, running a `while(true)`, sending a message to its "master" worker every time 1 millisecond has passed. **This works**, and the timer is accurate, however this is extremely resource-intensive. Just running this loop uses about 30% of my CPU.

Is there ANY other way of getting a fast clock to work? It can be as hacky as possible and abuse as many APIs as it needs, it just has to be A: Faster than a maximum setInterval speed & B: As resource-efficient as possible.

Comment: What do you need the clock for? For what tasks do you need events at 1kHz? Or do you not need events at all?

Comment: @Bergi I'm doing a rhythm game. Simply running a requestAnimationFrame loop won't cut it because my audio needs to have sub-frame accuracy.

Comment: So you need to play audio at those events? Or do you need to detect user input at that accuracy?

Comment: Can you use something like `window.performance.now()` to see how much time has passed between frames and then process all the events that should have happened? Why do you need a timer to fire at such intervals when user input and rendering only runs at max 60hz?

Comment: I use the events to play audio and handle user input, yes. It's especially important to me that audio runs at a millisecond-accuracy because any slight inaccuracy in rhythm is easy to pick out for the ear. Therefore, using a 60Hz frame refresh clock isn't sufficient. I do use that for visual updates, however.